# Wso2 apim 3.2 with Wso2 km 5.10

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a wso2 apim 3.2 setup up with wso2km 5.10. I have configured the Apim to pass Enduser attributes to the backend but cannot get the role claim returned. apim and the km manager are on separate machines. I seem to get just the standard claims returned. I have enable the required sections of the deployment.toml and I'm not seeing what I have wrong any help would be appreciated.

```
[apim.jwt]<br/>
enable = true<br/>
claim_dialect = "http://wso2.org/claims"<br/>
claims_extractor_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.token.ExtendedDefaultClaimsRetriever"
```

here it what is returned.

```
{<br/>
  "http://wso2.org/claims/apiname": "xxxxxxxx",<br/>
  "http://wso2.org/claims/applicationtier": "Unlimited",<br/>
  "http://wso2.org/claims/version": "1.0.0",<br/>
  "http://wso2.org/claims/keytype": "PRODUCTION",<br/>
  "iss": "wso2.org/products/am",<br/>
  "http://wso2.org/claims/applicationname": "xxxxxx",<br/>
  "http://wso2.org/claims/enduser": "xxxxxx",<br/>
  "http://wso2.org/claims/enduserTenantId": "-1234",<br/>
  "http://wso2.org/claims/applicationUUId": "348d1ff9-06f5-4f3f-aa94-83f32f4a1f2a",<br/>
  "http://wso2.org/claims/subscriber": "xxxxxxx",<br/>
  "azp": "NjYtixQB4VbFLeunCrj1U1ZYcfga",<br/>
  "http://wso2.org/claims/tier": "Unlimited",<br/>
  "scope": "openid",<br/>
  "exp": 1601500346,<br/>
  "http://wso2.org/claims/applicationid": "8",<br/>
  "http://wso2.org/claims/usertype": "Application_User",<br/>
  "http://wso2.org/claims/apicontext": "/xxxxxxxxxxx"<br/>
}

{
  "sub": "admin@carbon.super",
  "aud": "eZi3HFaydfnHtlZRZDpzuz6N5pMa",
  "nbf": 1602022037,
  "azp": "eZi3HFaydfnHtlZRZDpzuz6N5pMa",
  "scope": "am_application_scope default",
  "iss": "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "exp": 1602025637,
  "iat": 1602022037,
  "jti": "7845227d-6800-4ff2-9982-3d338e45abb6"
}
```

Comment: Could you please post generated JWT key? I'd like to see if access token, has role attributes.

Comment: that I posted above.

Comment: I believe this is the token passed to backend. What I'd like to see is the token generated to caller but anyway. The answer below should solve your issue...

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to include user claims to the backend JWT

1. Implement custom token generator
2. Adding required claims to the JWT access token

**Adding required claims to the JWT access token**

With APIM 3.2.0 it supports only JWT access token for the new application it registers. To include any user claims to backend JWT, the required claims should be in the JWT access token since GW is responsible to generate backend JWT.

To include user claims to the JWT access token follow the below steps.

1. Identify the service provider for the application from the management console
2. Edit the service provide and configure **requested claims** under the **Claim Configuration** menu
   [image]
3. Generate an access token with **openid** scope

```
    curl -k -X POST https://localhost:8243/token -d 
    "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=openid" -H"Authorization: Basic 
    VEJEMXJZazZpSWVlaTlnVzRNTENBYXNEQW9JYTpkRnJ0bVJjaklqUUtkSVVYeVY4aWxlZjBQNWdh"
```

4. An access token will be issued with the requested claims

```
    {
      "sub": "admin@carbon.super",
      "aud": "TBD1rYk6iIeei9gW4MLCAasDAoIa",
      "nbf": 1602047260,
      "azp": "TBD1rYk6iIeei9gW4MLCAasDAoIa",
      "scope": "am_application_scope openid",
      "iss": "https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token",
      "groups": [
        "Internal/subscriber",
        "Internal/creator",
        "Application/apim_devportal",
        "Application/admin_sample_PRODUCTION",
        "Internal/publisher",
        "Internal/everyone",
        "Internal/devops",
        "Application/apim_admin_portal",
        "Application/admin_key1_PRODUCTION",
        "admin",
        "Internal/analytics",
        "Application/apim_publisher"
      ],
      "exp": 1602050860,
      "iat": 1602047260,
      "jti": "d74a617e-e976-42f4-8323-c1c2271d046e"
    }
```

5. Access an API with the above access token and backend JWT contains the required claims.

Comment: I tried the above and did not get any groups returned in the access token

Comment: Did you do the required changes in IS 5.10.0?

Comment: yes I did what you advised above. Does it require jwt to be enabled on both the apim and the identity server?

Comment: No. APIM 320 JWT is generated by GW. So it needs to be enabled in GW only. Before using IS KM, can you try this with APIM only? I mean generate access token from APIM internal KM? So you can verify the flow

Comment: Ok that  worked without the IS KM. but once I add it back I get. "Failed to retrieve scopes of applicationlStOoESiSaf0Df3dZI7WIF_7nn8a java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'apim_db.AM_API_SCOPES' doesn't exist"  the apim and IS KM share the same database for apim_db and share_db. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: hope you have followed this(https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/configuring-wso2-identity-server-as-a-key-manager/). Didn't you used the APIM descript to create the schema in amdb?

Comment: yes I did follow that document when ran the test without the IS KM enabled it works fine when I have it enable this is the failure I get.

Comment: and the error is being generated on the IS KM and on the the APIM

Comment: is implicit still an option? for this setup?

Comment: also I looked at the apimgt mysql.sql script and their is no AM_API_SCOPES table being created in it. then checked 3.1 and their is. this is a fresh install of 3.2