# WSO2 apim get user roles in the backend

Tags: java, docker-compose, jwt, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have an instance of WSO2 apim 4.1.0 with IS 5.11.0 using docker compose, I need to get the roles of the logged in user when sending requests through the backend of an application exposed via OpenApi with the WSO2 gateway.

I tried to add the role as mandatory claim as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64237665/4623781) question but the token still does not contain the user roles.

Example token:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ik4ySmpNak5pTTJFeFlqUmtOelpqWm1ZMVlUQXhObUZsTmpnNE9XVTFZV1EyWXpjMU5tWTVOUT09In0=.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.iFVbpj3TG4UdtU3DhaLnMRGoIwfyHhenuCRr7C2t37lOlqJOsdLCeo0tGb_U5EsmdnHrN8kSscCG41v7JcOm97W5v7PKHtg95y3QKOTouzFppEq71DIXPmW51wDWh5EHNPFwXZ0e_371ZjXAOSB5UzStyzha7heg_DoPDTf1b6aLSP-9t50qsI4wT_HR7fm_Hmn-ZRL8ncmiuiQbofoGuTUHCmM1CfjiqQ_U65SAXgIKB2hATWaJFxqfr6emUsHMTdqS0_79DwxqHE_PdTQobBECOiU8RHZ_kxsQ1WpY__Ud9PEn13qRtGGV_Rp1LRd14iYF4l9ns1ENhNc1Tz0JNg==
```

Which translates to

```
{
  "sub": "testTerapeuta",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/apiname": "MapsEH",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/applicationtier": "Unlimited",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/version": "1.0.0",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/keytype": "PRODUCTION",
  "iss": "wso2.org/products/am",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/applicationname": "DefaultApplication",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/enduser": "testTerapeuta@carbon.super",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/enduserTenantId": "-1234",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/applicationUUId": "a0831cb6-37ec-4ea6-8894-c9b5fb35b2c0",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/subscriber": "testTerapeuta",
  "azp": "N8AVO3QW0dvYLVKsQhTy_wud7jwa",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/tier": "Unlimited",
  "scope": "default",
  "exp": 1662110537,
  "http://wso2.org/claims/applicationid": "1",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/usertype": "Application_User",
  "iat": 1662109637,
  "jti": "ab0ef354-fce3-4233-8323-3e8441c5c00b",
  "http://wso2.org/claims/apicontext": "/maps-eh/1.0.0"
}
```

I also tried to compile a custom token generator as shown in the [official docs](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy-and-publish/deploy-on-gateway/api-gateway/passing-enduser-attributes-to-the-backend-via-api-gateway/) but the result is the same, here is the java code that I compiled into a jar with `maven install`, filename `src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/test/CustomTokenGenerator.java` with the jar put in the path `<API-M_HOME>/repository/components/lib`.

```
import org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException;
import org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConstants;
import org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.TokenValidationContext;
import org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.token.JWTGenerator;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class CustomTokenGenerator extends JWTGenerator {

    public Map<String, String> populateStandardClaims(TokenValidationContext validationContext)
            throws APIManagementException {
        Map<String, String> claims = super.populateStandardClaims(validationContext);
        boolean isApplicationToken =
                validationContext.getValidationInfoDTO().getUserType().equalsIgnoreCase(APIConstants.ACCESS_TOKEN_USER_TYPE_APPLICATION) ? true : false;
        String dialect = getDialectURI();
        if (claims.get(dialect + "/enduser") != null) {
            if (isApplicationToken) {
                claims.put(dialect + "/enduser", "null");
                claims.put(dialect + "/enduserTenantId", "null");
            } else {
                String enduser = claims.get(dialect + "/enduser");
                if (enduser.endsWith("@carbon.super")) {
                    enduser = enduser.replace("@carbon.super", "");
                    claims.put(dialect + "/enduser", enduser);
                }
            }
            claims.put(dialect + "/role", "null");
        }

        return claims;

    }

    public Map<String, String> populateCustomClaims(TokenValidationContext validationContext) throws APIManagementException{
        Long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Map<String,String> customClaims = new HashMap<String, String>();
        customClaims.put("current_timestamp", time.toString());
        customClaims.put(getDialectURI() + "/scope", validationContext.getValidationInfoDTO().getScopes().toString());
        return customClaims;
    }
}
```

And also here is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.37
    ports:
      - 3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: *
    volumes:
      - ./conf/mysql/scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./conf/mysql/conf/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    ulimits:
      nofile:
        soft: 20000
        hard: 40000
    command: [--ssl=0]
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-uroot", "-proot"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 60s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 80s
  is-as-km:
    build: ./dockerfiles/is-as-km (image wso2/wso2is:5.11.0)
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "nc", "-z","localhost", "9444"]
      interval: 10s
      start_period: 180s
      retries: 20
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
      - ./conf/is-as-km:/home/wso2carbon/wso2-config-volume
    ports:
      - "9444:9444"
  api-manager:
    build: ./dockerfiles/apim (image wso2/wso2am:4.1.0)
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "nc", "-z","localhost", "9443"]
      interval: 10s
      start_period: 180s
      retries: 20
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
      is-as-km:
        condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
      - ./conf/apim:/home/wso2carbon/wso2-config-volume
    ports:
      - "9443:9443"
      - "8280:8280"
      - "8243:8243"
  backend:
    build: .
    restart: always
    container_name: myapp
    #working_dir: /app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "2999:3001"
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./src:/home/node/app/src
      - ./public:/home/node/app/public
      - ./node_modules:/home/node/app/node_modules
```

Finally the relevant part of my `deployment.toml` file following

```
[apim.jwt]
enable = true
encoding = "base64" #base64,base64url
#generator_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.test.CustomTokenGenerator"
generator_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.jwt.generator.APIMgtGatewayJWTGeneratorImpl"
claim_dialect = "http://wso2.org/claims"
#convert_dialect = false
header = "X-JWT-Assertion"
signing_algorithm = "SHA256withRSA"
enable_user_claims = true
claims_extractor_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.token.ExtendedDefaultClaimsRetriever"

#[apim.jwt.gateway_generator]
#impl = "org.wso2.carbon.test.CustomTokenGenerator"

[apim.key_manager]
service_url = "https://is-as-km:9444/services/"
type = "WSO2-IS"
```

Any hint about what may be wrong? Thanks

Comment: Since you are using IS 5.11.0 as a independent runtime, can you try installing the CustomTokenGenerator on the IS 5.11.0, as that is the place the keys are issued for APIM to consume.

Comment: Hi Ruwan, how do I install it inside IS? In the deployment.toml of IS 5.11.0 I don't have entries about jwt

Comment: Did you request openid scope when generating the access token?

Comment: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-security/openid-connect/obtaining-user-profile-information-with-openid-connect/#decoding-the-id_token

Comment: Hi Pubci, what I need is not to get the user information on the frontend but verify the user role in the backend called through api gateway to send different responses based on role on the same endpoint. The userinfo endpoint is not ideal as it would imply an additional network request everytime, or did I get it wrong?

Comment: Also I was using the IS as separate runtime only because I need PAP/PDP policies, in case it is possible to use Entitlement in APIM I could use only APIM without the IS.

Comment: I found this https://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/02/use-of-wso2-api-manager-to-validate-fine-grained-policy-decisions-using-xacml/ article but the jar plugin entitlement-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar is not linked anywhere